# Mule ESB does not able to pass a message property as input in Oracle Store Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, mule, mule-el

Good morning everybody,

I have a question for you about the mule's behviour when it has to execute a **Oracle Store Procedure** in MuleEE 3.4.

In my application I should invoke a Store Procedure in a Oracle Database and I should pass it an input variable (mule message id) and this procedure should return a value (0) in an output variable passed also itself in the store procedure as *out* variable. The code below shows this:

```
<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="JdbcConnector" doc:name="Database" queryKey="CallProcedure">
    <jdbc-ee:query key="CallProcedure" value="Call analyze_buffer_sbil_zonali(#[#[message.outboundProperties['massageID']];string;in],#[mules2;int;out])"/>
</jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
```

The problem is that I get this error when I try to excetue this query:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter IN or OUT missing in the index:: 2
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1680)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

I really do not how this exception is thrown. I followed the mule documentation ([JDBC Transport Reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference)) and I tried other variants of this query, but no changed occurred.

I've stopped here in development and I do not know how to carry on without using a Java class that implements this behaviour.

Does anybody any idea?

I look forward to hearing you,
thank you so much in advance

Comment: Does anybody have any idea? I would not use a specific Java class to run a Store Procedure. I would like to benefit from JDBC Mule component directly.